# Git can't find object

Tags: git

There are other similar questions, but this one is mine. It may (?) have a twist. The bottom line is that I can't push:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 48, done.
error: unable to find bef38a15fa2b35e5bae2210f48d4334486fb37ac
fatal: unable to get type of object bef38a15fa2b35e5bae2210f48d4334486fb37ac
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:me/project-name.git'
```

Sure enough, if I try to find a file by this name in `.git/objects`, nothing is returned.

```
find .git/objects -name bef38a15fa2b35e5bae2210f48d4334486fb37ac
```

So my first thought was to just grab that object from another repository where things are just fine. Except that no object by that name exists there either.

Any idea what I might have done? Or, more importantly, how I can fix it? I'm working with git 1.5.4.3.

Comment: It is possible that that commit was only in your computer, so no other repository has it. In such a case you normally have no way to get it back. It happened to me once and I had to do it again

Comment: The object file (if it exists) will be called `f38a15fa2b35e5bae2210f48d4334486fb37ac` and it will be in `.git/objects/be`.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. Same result in the other repo, but at least I'm looking in the right place. That's a start. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one of your objects from your local repository has been lost. I'm afraid that means the only way to fix your repo is removing everything that is directly related to that object (whatever it is).

A `git fsck` will probably give you more information on the exact cause of your problem.

Comment: Okay, looks like the file has a 0 byte length. It's not actually _my_ repository that's corrupt so I'll have to get more info from the actual user to see what he did and why. Further bulletins as events warrant...

Comment: Looks like it's lost. For whatever reason, the developer thought his only course of action was to delete the file from `.git/objects/be` and then, when git complained about it missing, try to put it back. We're calling it a total loss. Thanks for your help.